# Passing a Custom Object, an NSObject sub - Class, with a Storyboard Segue

Tags: parameter-passing, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue, custom-object

SimpleTest Object:

my .h (header) code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SimpleTest : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *tested;
@end
```

my .m code:

```
#import "SimpleTest.h"
@implementation SimpleTest
@synthesize tested;
@end
```

Just a simple class.  I made this for a test, I actually have a bigger more complex object.

in my storyboard if I pass an object I didn't make, for example an NSString, in the prepareForSegue from my original ViewController to my DestinationViewController, it works just fine; the destination view controller gets it fine.  When I pass the simple object I made from the origin ViewController and set the string, it returns null in the Destination ViewController here is some sample code:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toInsulinList"]) 
{
    IDataViewController *ivc = [segue destinationViewController];
    ivc.pListObj = self.pListObj; //My complex object, returns null in dest vc 
    ivc.tester = @"Tested"; //this is an NSString in dest vc - works fine
    simpleTest.tested = @"testObj";   
    ivc.simpleTest = self.simpleTest; //my simple object, returns null in dest vc
}
```

Any guesses on this?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object was nil.  Rookier error. :(